# Getting couchrest and couch_potato to recognize existing couchdb documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, couchdb, couchrest, couchpotato

I'm trying to create a basic Rails CRUD app against a CouchDB database hosted on Cloudant.

I'm using [couch_potato](https://github.com/langalex/couch_potato) as my persistence layer and have it connecting properly to my Cloudant database.

The issues I'm having is my first model won't see the existing documents in my CouchDB database, *unless* I add a `ruby_class` field that equals the name of my model.

**My simple User model:**

```
class User
  include CouchPotato::Persistence

   property :id, :type => Fixnum
   property :FullName, :type => String

   view :all, :key => :FullName
end
```

**Sample CouchDB document:**

```
{
  "_id": 123456,
  "_rev": "4-b96f36763934ce7c469abbc6fa05aaf3",
  "ORGID": 400638,
  "MyOrgToken": "19fc342d50f9d8df1ecd5e5404f5e5f7",
  "FullName": "Jane Doe",
  "Phone": "555-555-5555",
  "MemberNumber": 123456,
  "Email": "jane@example.com",
  "LoginPWHash": "14a3ccc0e6a50135ef391608e786f4e8"
}
```

Now, when I use my `all` view from the rails console, I don't get any results back:

```
1.9.2-p290 :002 > CouchPotato.database.view User.all
=> []
```

If I add the field and value `"ruby_class: User"` to the above CouchDB document, then I get results back in the console:

```
1.9.2-p290 :003 > CouchPotato.database.view User.all
=> [#<User _id: "123456", _rev: "4-b96f36763934ce7c469abbc6fa05aaf3", created_at: nil,       
   updated_at: nil, id: "123456", FullName: "Jane Doe">]
```

I'm working with a large set of customer data, and I don't want to write any scripts to add the `ruby_class` field to every document (and I may not be permitted to).

How can I get my app to recognize these existing CouchDB documents without adding the `ruby_class` field?

I couldn't find much documentation for couch_potato and couchrest that shows how to work with existing CouchDB databases. Most of the examples assume you're starting your project and database(s) from scratch.

Thanks,

/floatnspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are looking at the `all` view of your `User` you will see something like `ruby_class == 'User'` so unless you add this property to your documents you will need to work around what couch_potato provides. you could i.e. use couch_rest directly to retrieve your documents, but i don't think that this what you want.

if you start persisting or updating your own documents, couch_potato will add the `ruby_class` field anyways. so i think the simples solution would be to just add them there.

another thing you can do is create a view that emits the documents also when they DON'T have the property set. this approach will only work if you have just one kind of document in your couchdb:

```
if(!doc.ruby_class || doc.ruby_class == 'User') {
  emit(doc);
}
```

Comment: Ahh. I see that couch_potato is cooking the check `if(doc.ruby_class && doc.ruby_class == 'User')` directly into the `all` view as you suspected. I may look into using couchrest or simple HTTP and JSON processing instead. My plan was to use couchrest_model, but Cloudant has come out and said they don't support couchrest_model and discourage its use.